# PHP Create directory (Error: No such file or directory)?

Tags: php

I'm having a small issue here with my php where I'm trying to create a directory but when the code is ran I get the error message

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Can anyone give me some guidance as to where I'm going wrong here?

```
<?
    function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }

    $Key = generateRandomString();

    if(is_dir("Server1/".$Key) === true){
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else
    {
        mkdir("Server1/".$Key);
        echo $Key;
    }

?>
```

Comment: check if `Server1` exists

Comment: Server1 100% exists as the document I'm writing the php in is saved in this directory

Comment: Then you should be leaving out the Server1 part, or be using an absolute path. Right now you are referring to `Server1/Server1/$key`

Comment: Ahhh that makes so much sense, Thanks John V "lifesaver"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_dir("Server1/".$Key) === true){
    header("Refresh:0");
}
else
{
    mkdir("Server1/".$Key);
    echo $Key;
}
```

The call to [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) fails when the directory `"Server1/".$Key` does not exist but it also fails when the directory `Server1` does not exist.

On the other hand, by default, [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) does not create the intermediate directories when they do not exist. If the directory `Server1` does not exist then `is_dir()` returns `FALSE` and `mkdir()` fails with the error message "No such file or directory".

It makes sense because in order to create the directory `"Server1/".$Key` it must first go to the `"Server1/"` directory and create the sub-directory `$Key` inside it.

You can make it work by passing `TRUE` as the third argument of [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
mkdir("Server1/".$Key, 0777, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

`bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )`

You need to set recursive to true:

> recursive
>
> Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.

Alternatively, if you expect the sub path to exist, you may want to check your path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your php script is in the "Server1" directory you dont want to use "Server1" in mkdir...

Just use 
    mkdir($Key);